# Tcl: Producing a Loop (*)

Tags: tcl

I want to produce a loop in Tcl that if n=2 creates:

```
set Beam_Gravity_Load [subst {$a $b}]
```

if n=3:

```
set Beam_Gravity_Load [subst {$a $a $b}]
```

if n=4:

```
set Beam_Gravity_Load [subst {$a $a $a $b}]
```

if n=5:

```
set Beam_Gravity_Load [subst {$a $a $a $a $b}]
```

and so on. "n" always is greater than 2. How do I do?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing you're looking for is `lrepeat` in combination with `{*}`:

```
set Beam_Gravity_Load [list {*}[lrepeat [expr {$n-1}] $a] $b]
```

You could also do it with `for`:

```
set value {}
for {set i 1} {$i < $n} {incr i} {
    lappend value $a
}
lappend value $b
set Beam_Gravity_Load $value
```

(If the `Beam_Gravity_Load` variable isn't linked/traced, you can avoid the extra `value` variable.)